# fading in of li elements in order jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

I'm trying to fade in this list which is set to display:none, in order, after clicking on a separate image. Just doesn't do anthing. idk whats wrong.
Here's full thing: https://codepen.io/saintnicks78/pen/mmojMR
js:

```
$('.fade').on('click', function() {
   $('.centered li').each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(2000)




      })
  })
```

jade:

```
p
    a.fade(href="#")
     img.fade(src='http://data.whicdn.com/images/18140107/large.jpg', height='150', width='200').semi

  p 
    ul.centered
      li
      li Chapter 1 
      li Chapter 2
      li Chapter 3
      li Chapter 4
      li Chapter 5
      li Chapter 6
      li Chapter 7
      li Chapter 8
      li Chapter 9
```

I already tried the solution in that post. jQuery is included also as i can do other things with it.

Comment: Assuming you have a problem, can you describe it?

Comment: it doesnt do anything lol.

Comment: https://codepen.io/saintnicks78/pen/mmojMR

Comment: Well your console states: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` so it is not going to do anything since jQuery was not included.

Comment: just checked and console is clear.

Comment: @milanchheda not rly i seen that post and doesnt work for me.

Comment: Oh Ok. In that case, let me check your codepen.

Comment: It says `$ is not defined`. Seems JQuery is not getting loaded. I not sure, but may be something wrong in Jade. I don't know much of Jade, hence can't really confirm the issue.

Comment: jQuery is not included.

Comment: is this not jquery?
 lol: 
 script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js')

Comment: The page at 'https://codepen.io/saintnicks78/pen/mmojMR' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Should load if you change the jquery url to use https.  "Lol"

Comment: ?. loads fine for me without https. it's not a jquery issue, i can do other things with it, just won't fadein this list.

Comment: Check browser console.

Comment: I did,  its good there too.

Comment: Well done you fixed the https problem.  Now, it's just a matter of putting display:none on the LI elements instead of on the UL.

Comment: certainly better now thanks. however it doesnt do the fade effect, they pop in.

Comment: Try removing all the transition css for the LIs.

Comment: works perfectly now, thanks!